# No Individual User Accounts auth option in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API template

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am a bit confused as to why there is no Individual User Accounts authentication option in the latest `ASP.NET Core` Web API template.

Is it still possible to implement individual user accounts the way that the `MVC` template does or would it not make sense?

Let's say I am creating a `stand-alone` web API that is going to have all of my business logic and data layer that accesses the database which has the `AspNet` Identity tables. I plan on making calls to this API w/o an MVC app.

I know one way of doing this is to create an `asp.net` `MVC` app w/o individual user accounts `auth` and simply build the API right within the MVC app using a controllers/api folder.
However, I don't want to do it this way because I want the API to be its own standalone project that can be hosted on a completely different server and accessed by multiple applications, not just an MVC app.

Can someone lead me in the right direction on how authentication typically works in this scenario since there is no template?

Comment: The templates are moving to nuget packages so the templates can be updated independently from VS, hopefully soon we'll see more options in the templates.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but its not just web api project it's the same behavior wrt mvc project.

But its still possible to get it working by copying the files over to your project manually. Or you can look for a template online to see if anyone else has done it. I'm in the process of doing the same for myself. Maybe I'll expose it as a template and let you know so you can pull it.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also follow this:https://forums.asp.net/t/2126983.aspx?Why+the+user+account+store+in+visual+studio+template+not+attached+to+the+web+api+